# Dapper AddDynamicParams for IN statement with "dynamic" parameter name

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dapper

I have  simple SQL string like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Office WHERE OfficeId IN @Ids"
```

The thing is that the @Ids name is entered in an editor so it could be whatever, and my problem is that if I want to pass in, say an array of integers, it only works with Dapper if I use:

```
var values = new DynamicParameters();
values.AddDynamicParams(new { Ids = new[] { 100, 101 } });
```

But this requires me to KNOW that the parameter name is `Ids` and that's not the case in my scenario.

I can set a "dynamic parameter" in Dapper with a "dynamic" name like this:

```
var values = new DynamicParameters();
values.Add("Ids", new[] { 100, 101 });
```

But then Dapper doesn't construct the `IN (....)` SQL with separate parameters for each value.

Is there a way to construct the dynamic object passed in to `AddDynamicParams` but setting the member name and value without knowing the name beforehand?

I could modify the Dapper source to work for my scenario, but if anyone know of a simpler and elegant solution to this I would be greatful!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have just submitted a fix to the repository that allows any of the following to work correctly:

by object (this worked previously):

```
values.AddDynamicParams(new { ids = list });
```

or, by single name:

```
values.Add("ids", list);
```

or, as a dictionary:

```
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
args.Add("ids", list);
values.AddDynamicParams(args);
```

I have not yet deployed to NuGet. Let me know if this is a problem.

Comment: Thanks alot Marc! Works like a charm!

This is why I love open source.. Superb job!

Comment: @Jaynard meh, you can get fast fixes in both open-source and closed-source. To really be an example of the advantage of open-source, you would have sent me a pull request to the fix ;p

Comment: hehe that's true, and I had just started looking through the source code but you beat me to it by a landslide ;)

Comment: @MarcGravell, in your example it looks like `list` is a data type. I'm familiar with `List<T>` but not `list` could you clarify what it is in your example?

Comment: As a side note for Postgres users, the SQL would be: '"SELECT * FROM Office WHERE OfficeId = ANY (@Ids)'.  This threw me for a loop.

Comment: Awesome.  Wish I found this 3 hours ago!